# Oracle Execution Performance of a Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I have a procedure inside a Database package that does the follow:

- The procedure receives one ID to table - TESTTABLE.
- Then we open a cursor, and for each row on TESTETABLE executes +/- 40 queries that will get some reference data, like decoding Codes, getting more info, etc. These queries depend on inputs of each row from TESTTABLE, so they are dynamically created and execute.
- For each row processed, and insert is made in another table.

So far so good.

When TESTTABLE has 60 lines, the Execution time of the procedure is about 10 seconds (~60*40 queries plus 60 inserts on a table);

When TESTTABLE  for instance 120 lines, the Execution time is ~30mints  (120*40 queries plus 120 inserts). That is unacceptable!

I can't understand why this is happening, passing from a few seconds to dozens for minutes.

Can you help me to resolve this? Getting this execution on a fewer time?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Would it be possible to show us the code? Along with the table structure and the indexes on the columns.

Comment: Is it getting different 'more info' when there are more rows? Maybe one of the dynamic queries is only called for one of the new rows, and is causing the slow-down. You'll need to narrow it down though, we can't do that for you.